# Cant access Azure SQL server from nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, azure

I am trying to do a simple query to my azure SQL server from NodeJs, im getting errors that i cannot connect to the server. all the details are correct because i used them on another application i built in C#.

my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var config =
{
    host: Server,
    user: UserName,
    password: PassWord,
    database: Database
};

const conn = new mysql.createConnection(config);

conn.connect(
    function (err) { 
    if (err) { 
        console.log("!!! Cannot connect !!! Error:");
        throw err;
    }
    else
    {
       console.log("Connection established.");
           queryDatabase();
    }
});

function queryDatabase(){
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM Drinks', function (err, results, fields) 
    { 
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log(results);
    })

    conn.end(function (err) { 
    if (err) throw err;
    else  console.log('Done.') 
    });
};
```

I have tried making port rules, allowing nodejs through firewall, turning off firewall, I have added my IP to the firewall on the azure group and still cant connect. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\test.js:14:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i worked out how to do it! and for anyone with similar issues do this.

Instead of mysql i used mssql and it worked straight away.

Example:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    server: "XXX.database.windows.net",
    database: "XXX",
    user: "XXX",
    password: "XXX",
    port: 1433,
    options: {
          encrypt: true
      }
   };
   
   sql.connect(config).then(function() { 
       console.log("connected") 
       
       sql.query('SELECT * FROM Drinks', function (err, results, fields) 
        { 
            if (err) throw err; 
            console.log(results);
        })
    })
```